# fit function of Matlab is really slow

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Why is the `fit`function from Matlab so slow? I'm trying to fit a `gauss4` so I can get the means of the gaussians.

here's my plot,

[image]

I want to get the means from the blue data and red data.

I'm fitting a gaussian there but this function is really slow.

Is there an alternative?

```
    fa = fit(fn', facm', 'gauss4');

    acm = [fa.b1 fa.b2 fa.b3 fa.b4];

    a_cm = sort(acm, 'ascend');
```

Comment: Please see this thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/37900

Comment: The best way to improve a nonlinear curve fit is to supply good starting values. You can also use a partitioned least squares, which will significantly reduce the size of the parameter space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would apply some of the [options](http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/fit.html) available with `fit`. These include smoothing by setting `SmoothingParam` (your data is quite noisy, the alternative of applying a time domain filter may also help*), and setting the values of your initial parameter estimates, with `StartPoint`. Your fits may also not be converging because you set your tolerances (`TolFun`, `TolX`) too low, although from inspection of your fits that does not appear to be the case, in fact the opposite is likely, you probably want to increase the `MaxIter` and/or `MaxFunEvals`.

To figure out how to get going you can also try the `Spectr-O-Matic` [toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32828-spectr-o-matic). It requires Matlab 7.12. It includes a script called `GaussFit.m` to fit `gauss4` to data, but it also uses the `fit` routine and provides examples on how to set and get parameters.

- Note that smoothing will of course broaden your peaks, but you can subtract the contribution after the fact. The effect on the mean should not be deleterious, on the contrary, since you are presumably removing noise this should be more accurate.

Comment: the main problem is that it is too slow.

Comment: hehe, yeah... how slow? Applying some of these options may reduce the number of iterations required for convergence, accelerating things.

Comment: the only alternative is to try a different fitting algorithm, `fit` uses Levenberg-Marquardt as default as would most non-linear fitting routines for handling this type of problem. In fact I don't know that you can do much better than L-M.

Answer (score 0):

In general functions will be faster if you apply it to a shorter series. Hence, if speedup is really important you could downsample.

For example, if you have a vector that you want to downsample by a factor 2: (you may need to make sure it fits first)

```
n = 2;
x = sin(0.01:0.01:pi);
x_downsampled = x(1:n:end)+x(2:n:end);
```

You will now see that x_downsampled is much smaller (and should thus be easier to process), but will still have the same shape. In your case I think this is sufficient.
To see what you got try:
plot(x)

Now you can simply process `x_downsampled` and map your solution, for example

```
f = find(x_downsampled == max(x_downsampled));
location_of_maximum = f * n;
```

Needless to say this should be done in combination with the most efficient options that the `fit` function has to offer.